# Linking a library built from source code to a program managed by autotools

Tags: c, linker, autotools

I have a c program which needs a library named libnuma to be installed. But I dont have root access in the parallel machine in which I need to run this program.  So  I downloaded the source code of libnuma and compiled it.  I have a libnuma.a file which i assume is the library.  I need to link this library with the c program that I have.  This program uses autotools for generating the configuration files and the makefile.  I am new to autotools.  Please tell me what I have to do to link this library without being root.

Ajay.

Comment: When you said "which being root" did you mean "without being root"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be sufficient to set CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS.  First, try:

```
$ ./configure LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/include
```

(where libnuma.a is /path/to/lib/libnuma.a and numa.h is /path/to/include/numa.h.
That is, specify the directories.)  If that does not work, check config.log to see what went wrong.  If the configure script for the program you are using was built with an old version of autoconf, you may need to do:

```
$ LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/include ./configure
```

instead.  (The second invocation will only work in Bourne shells.  With csh/tcsh, you will need to set the environment variables some other way, for example with env.)  You also have the option of making those settings in the environment of your shell (eg, in a .bashrc) or in a config.site file.

Comment: Hi I tried this.  I am using the libnuma library.  The configure still says libnuma not present.  If I install libnuma using apt-get with root access it detects the presence of the library.  But I dont have root access in the machine that I have to run it finally.  Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Check config.log to see why it is not detecting libnuma.  It is possible (and unfortunately quite common) for developers to produce configure scripts that do not correctly recognize the user settings for LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS.  Another possibility is that you have a stale cache (search for "cache" in config.log).  Search for libnuma in config.log.  When checking for numa.h, the configure script just tries to compile a program that #includes it, and the config.log will show you exactly what command was run.  Similarly when finding the library.  Search for "numa" in config.log.